# Webpack not recognizing Node's process module

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

After not touching Javascript for over a decade I had an idea for an app that will work best when implemented as a NodeJS app. I read up on the modern JS ecosystem and like most people I'm thoroughly confused, haha.

Seems like the combination of NodeJS, TypeScript and Webpack is a good way to go, but I'm having issues even getting a simple Hello World working.

The one TypeScript file I wrote, `./src/run_task.ts`:

```
// #!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * @file Main application file. Users start the app by running `node dist/run_task.js`
 * @author Gerard Leenhouts
 */

import * as process from "process";

function main(): number {
    console.log(process);
    console.log(`Got ${process.argv.length} arguments.`);
    return 42;
}

main();
```

When I execute `tsc` manually (`tsc -p server.tsconfig.json`) it works fine, but when I execute `webpack` it seems to create it's own definition of the `process` module in the resulting .js file. Here's a part of it:

```
process.nextTick = function (fun) {
    var args = new Array(arguments.length - 1);
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            args[i - 1] = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    queue.push(new Item(fun, args));
    if (queue.length === 1 && !draining) {
        runTimeout(drainQueue);
    }
};

// v8 likes predictible objects
function Item(fun, array) {
    this.fun = fun;
    this.array = array;
}
Item.prototype.run = function () {
    this.fun.apply(null, this.array);
};
process.title = 'browser';
process.browser = true;
process.env = {};
process.argv = [];
process.version = ''; // empty string to avoid regexp issues
process.versions = {};

function noop() {}

process.on = noop;
process.addListener = noop;
process.once = noop;
process.off = noop;
process.removeListener = noop;
process.removeAllListeners = noop;
process.emit = noop;
process.prependListener = noop;
process.prependOnceListener = noop;

process.listeners = function (name) { return [] }

process.binding = function (name) {
    throw new Error('process.binding is not supported');
};

process.cwd = function () { return '/' };
process.chdir = function (dir) {
    throw new Error('process.chdir is not supported');
};
process.umask = function() { return 0; };
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "startpage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Self hosted web app to function as a web browser startpage",
  "main": "run_task.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node dist/run_task.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Gerard Leenhouts",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^9.4.6",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [
    {
        // devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        entry: './src/run_task.ts',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'ts-loader',
                            options: { configFile: 'server.tsconfig.json' }
                        }
                    ],
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'run_task.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        }
    }
];
```

My `server.tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": { "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"] },
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "include": [ "./src/**/*" ]
}
```

I've been going through the Webpack and TypeScript documentation for hours now, and can't seem to figure it out.  It's quite possible I'm overlooking something simple but I can't see the forest for the trees anymore. Obviously it has something to do with module resolution but everything seems fine in the config files, as far as I can tell. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems to create it's own definition of the process module in the
>   resulting .js file

In your `webpack.config.js` you need to set the `target` to `node`. Just add `target: 'node'` at the same level as `output`. This will compile for usage in a Node.js-like environment (uses Node.js require to load chunks and not touch any built in modules like process, fs, etc). Docs here: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

Answer (score 0):

Webpack's by default compile build for target "web". So To resolve your issue just use target value "node".

{
target: "node"
}

Because client side code can also contain some Node js" global variable like "process.env". so webpack poly-fill those variable in web target build.

More more advanced case and control. "node" property can also be used directly.
https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/node/