# Webpack with target node/electron-main not recognizing import node:process

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I updated the node module [fix-path](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path)because it was crashing intermittently.

After updating the node module I cannot use it in my main.js file as it throws the following error:
[image: Error received when using updated node module]

So instead of using it in the main js, I moved this piece of code to a different file which goes through the webpack build process. But then the webpack build fails as it does not recognize 'node:process'.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/default-shell/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'node:os' in '/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/default-shell'
resolve 'node:os' in '/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/default-shell'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/default-shell/package.json (relative path: .)
    resolve as module
      /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/default-shell/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/shashi/projects/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/shashi/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/node:os)
            no extension
              /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os doesn't exist
            *
              /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os* doesn't exist
            .js
              /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os.js doesn't exist
            .json
              /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os doesn't exist
[/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/default-shell/node_modules]
[/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node_modules]
[/Users/shashi/projects/node_modules]
[/Users/shashi/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os]
[/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os*]
[/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os.js]
[/Users/shashi/projects/trici-atman-desktop/node_modules/node:os.json]
 @ ./node_modules/default-shell/index.js 2:0-33 12:18-26
 @ ./node_modules/shell-env/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/shell-path/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/fix-path/index.js
 @ ./desktopServices/AppService.js
 @ ./desktopServices/desktopServices.js
```

After seeing the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854172/webpack-not-recognizing-nodes-process-module) question, I tried changing the target of my webpack from electron-main to node. But it still did not recognize.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by upgrading webpack from 4 to 5.